# querydsl instance variables

Tags: jpa, querydsl

From [QueryDSL JPA Tutorial](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.5.0/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e202), I could not find differences between default instance variable generated by querydsl and custom variable.

For the entity Customer defined as

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fn){
        firstName = fn;
    }

    public void setLastName(String ln)[
        lastName = ln;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between using default instance variable and custom as follows ?

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
```

VS

```
QCustomer customer = new QCustomer("myCustomer");
```

What could be the possible use cases for custom variable as in second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable name is used as such in the serialization. If you need to refer to multiple instances of the same type in your query, you need to use multiple variables.

Here is an example

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
QCustomer customer2 = new QCustomer("customer2");
List<Customer> customers = query.from(customer)
     .where(new JPASubQuery()
         .from(customer2)
         .where(customer2.id.ne(customer.id),
                customer2.lastName.eq(customer.lastName),
                customer2.firstName.eq(customer.firstName))
         .exists())
     .list(customer);
```

Comment: Is it ok if I use default variable in all queries where there is only one instance of QCustomer to be used?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect: yes, that would be their intended use.